# Bayesian estimate of a Gamma distribution scale parameter

Tags: bayesian, estimation, gamma-distribution

I saw [a material](http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/v9n1/elfessi.html) showing Bayesian estimation on a Gamma distribution scale parameter. As shown below.
[image]

I think in the 2nd formula, the denominator should be integrated by theta, which is the formal Bayesian estimation definition. Is there any problem with it? or I missed something? I don't quite understand the symbol right in the middle of the formula means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second formula is one version of [Bayes' formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_theorem), that you may have heard of:
$$\begin{align*}\pi(\theta|X_1,\ldots,X_n) &= \dfrac{\pi(\theta) f(X_1,\ldots,X_n|\theta)}{\int_0^{\infty} \pi(\theta) f(X_1,\ldots,X_n|\theta)\text{d}\theta}\\ &\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}
\dfrac{\pi(\theta) f(X_1,\ldots,X_n|\theta)}{f(X_1,\ldots,X_n)}\end{align*}$$where $f(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ denotes the marginal density of the vector $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$.

Note that, contrary to what is written in this excerpt, the prior $$\pi(\theta)\propto\theta^{\alpha-1}\exp\{-\beta\theta\}\mathbb{I}_{\theta>0}$$is not an improper prior when $\alpha>0$, $\beta>0$. And that the extension $\alpha<0$ makes little sense since it requires a minimal sample size to operate, hence depends on the data.

Comment: appreciate it : )